# RESTful Jersey multiple resources and package

Tags: jersey, restful-architecture

I have a simple project RESTful API using Jersey framework, and Netbean SDK.

I created a resource and put it in a different package other than the default, and also specified the package in XML file:
[The resource is CustomerProfile, and package is Profile. Package "Profile" is not part of the default package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EFZ2.png) 
Here is my XML :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>trial1.jerseytutorial</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>Profile</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I also define the resource in CustomerProfile.java

```
package Profile;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
@Path("/CustomerProfile")        // the URL path leading to the resource
public class CustomerProfile {
@GET            // map the method to HTTP Get 
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)   // tell the return format of the request
    public String getProfile() {
        return "Got the profile !";
    }
}
```

However, as I navigate to http://localhost:8080/JerseyTutorial/webapi/CustomerProfile I get 404 error. I suspect that my XML servlet is not right.

Answer (score 1):

Use comma (or semi-colon) delimiter

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>
        trial1.jerseytutorial,
        Profile
    </param-value>
</init-param>
```

Haven't tried it, but I think even new-line separation (without need for comma or semi-colon) even works.

Comment: it does work. It seems that I created a "subpackage", but not a package. Therefore, I should have used just :
    <init-param>
          <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
          <param-value>trial1.jerseytutorial</param-value>
    </init-param>

on my Java class, I could name my package as: trial1.jerseytutorial.Profile
in stead of just profile. 

I am still confused on how to create a different package, not a subpackage though